# Applying Baum-Welch to multiple observed sequences iteratively

Tags: hidden-markov-models

When using the Baum-Welch algorithm to train a hidden markov model you normally repeat it on some observed sequence iteratively until your values converge.

If you have multiple observed sequences, Wikipedia tells you to run the update on all sequences in parallel and then combine them into a new model and then apply this process iteratively.

Is it also possible to run on different observed sequences iteratively, one after the other? I.e, first train on sequence S1, then on sequence S2, then S3, ... then Sn, then start from S1 again. Would this converge at all?